# How do I get rid of a margin I did not assign?

Tags: css, margins

This is all I have in my css:

```
    .menu {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

html {
     background-image: url('image.jpg');
     background-size:cover;
}
```

But for some reason, this bar still has margins. Why? There is no text or anything in my div.

Comment: ops. please show html code too, this is too unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the browsers have default margins for "major" elements, it might be what you see. Try adding this at the beginning of your css to reset all those and work more consistently cross browsers :

```
/* css reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped, I suggest you always do that to have the same result cross-browsers.
If my answer solved your issue please validate it for futur people with the same issue :)